# Non-empty function on calculated Measure

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I wrote a calculated measure as follows

```
With member [Measures].[Path] as 
Iif (condition, DisplayIteration, null)


Select [Measures].[Path] ,
[Measures].[Caption],
[Measures].[Value] on 0 , 
{NonEmpty 
(
Crossjoin (
[Item].[Product],
Descendants ([Item].[Iteration])
)
, Descendants ([Item].[Iteration])
)
}on 1 from [Item]
```

The [Measures].[Path] is a report parameter label and [Measures].[Value] is a report parameter value. Since the filter is applied over Descendants ([Item].[Iteration] the null values of [Measures].[Path] are still seen.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try `NON EMPTY` for the rows instead of the `NonEmpty` function? Why are you "not able to apply non empty function her"? I see no reason for that in your question.

Comment: @FrankPl Thanks for your response. I made changes to the code please suggest a solution for this scenario.

Comment: Is your requirement to not show rows where all three measures are NULL? Or is it to not show rows where `[Measures].[Path]` is null? In the latter case, do you want to see rows where `[Measures].[Path]` is zero?

Comment: @FrankPl I want it to show the rows where [Measures].[Path] is not null. No, i dont want to see [Measures].[Path] value as zero. Tried to give second expression of NonEmpty as [Measure].[Path] but it is changing the data so I had to leave Descendants ([Item].[Iteration]).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to non empty, u can try exists() with MeasureGroupName parameter. The NullProcessing property of the measure may not be set to Preserve

You might have a look at the following thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f5ee3df4-3fc7-44ff-9248-c5a3a384ea4e/exists-vs-nonempty?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Philip,

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities to approach your requirement:

Either use `[Measures].[Path]` as the second argument to `NonEmpty`:

```
With member [Measures].[Path] as 
Iif (condition, DisplayIteration, null)

Select [Measures].[Path] ,
[Measures].[Caption],
[Measures].[Value] on 0 , 
{NonEmpty 
(
Crossjoin (
[Item].[Product],
Descendants ([Item].[Iteration])
)
, { [Measures].[Path] }
)
}on 1 from [Item]
```

or use `HAVING` instead of `NonEmpty`, which can be more selective on the condition:

```
With member [Measures].[Path] as 
Iif (condition, DisplayIteration, null)

Select [Measures].[Path] ,
[Measures].[Caption],
[Measures].[Value] on 0 , 
Crossjoin (
[Item].[Product],
Descendants ([Item].[Iteration])
)
Having Not [Measures].[Path] Is null
on 1 from [Item]
```

I am not sure about the effects on correctness of the result or performance, you will have to test that.

Comment: Tried both the ways
1. When using [Measures].[Path] as second argument, it is removing all the null values but displaying lot more iterations than it is supposed to be. Only on giving Descendants ([Work Item].[Hierarchy]) the required iterations are pulled (but as you know it still has the null value issue)
2. When using “having” a lot of iterations are pulled and also the null issue remains.

Comment: @user2974732 Maybe then you should try a combined approach: Keeping the `NonEmpty` with `Descendants ([Work Item].[Hierarchy])` as the second argument, and adding the `Having Not [Measures].[Path] Is null` before the `on 1`.

Comment: tried the combined approach. It is same as the one without Having Not [Measures].[Path] Is Null